# Can I run Laravel Queues from my home PC?

Tags: laravel, queue, high-load

Lets say, I have a production VPS with Laravel app which runs fine.

There are some tasks that are processed with queues. The queue driver is set to Database.

Can I connect my home PC to production DB and mail (like if my production is connected to mailgun then pass its credentials) and run queue workers with my home PC to take some load from the VPS?

I have an old laptop with Ubuntu 4gb RAM and 2 cores. That might save 40$ per month on renting the same tier VPS on DO or Linode. (ok, lets say 20$ cause of course it won't be full powered).

Comment: You probably could, but you **REALLY REALLY SHOULDN'T**. There's a reason production servers cost more than to run your own machine. They're running on reliable hardware, they're in a datacenter with reliable and highspeed network connections, reliable electrical grid with backup generators, they have backups in place and redundancies for a lot of things and the list can go on. If something goes wrong they've got you covered. But running an old computer in a room somewhere, through a home internet connection to be a production server dependency is something that nobody should ever do.

Comment: @Bogdan I am just thinking in terms of 'possibility'. By the way - managing queues is not the same as if you for instanse using a pc in a database cluster. If a queue machine fails - the load will just go to other machines. Queues are designed in the way, that if a queue job fails, it returns to the queue. I am not going to use such a setup anyways, but I am curious just to deepen my level of understanding on scaling and stuff.

Comment: I was under the impression that you wanted to run job processing solely on a different machine altogether (your laptop) to take the load from your main production server. Am I misunderstanding and you actually want to have multiple machines that process jobs?

Comment: @Bogdan - I am personally not into setting any queue workers right now. The purpose of the question is only to understand the architecture of the queue task runners. I was trying to add some 'virtual requirements' to be sure that other people understand what type of situation I am trying to describe.